# How to convert 32bit Excel VBA code to 64bit?

Tags: excel, vba, 32bit-64bit

could you please help with below code conversion to 64bit Excel?

```
Public Function ToUTF8(s As String) As Byte()

  If Len(s) = 0 Then Exit Function


  Dim ccb As Long
  ccb = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, StrPtr(s), Len(s), ByVal 0&, 0, vbNullString, ByVal 0&)

  If ccb = 0 Then
    Err.Raise 5, , "Internal error."
  End If

  Dim b() As Byte
  ReDim b(1 To ccb)

  If WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, StrPtr(s), Len(s), b(LBound(b)), ccb, vbNullString, ByVal 0&) = 0 Then
    Err.Raise 5, , "Internal error."
  Else
    ToUTF8 = b
  End If
  
End Function
```

I tried changing Long to longPtr and b to x, but I still get a comlilation error that I am not able to solve :-S

Comment: You firstly must correctly adapt the called API. How did you adapt it? What compilation error is raised? What `CP_UTF8` constant do you use?

Comment: There are also these definitions in the module: `Private Const CP_UTF8 As LongPtr = 65001
Private Const ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER As LongPtr = 122&` And I am getting a Compile error, Type Mismatch on the ReDim x(l To ccb), the ccb. Would you have any idea what needs to be updated? Sorry, I dont have much experience with the x64 code.

Comment: Where from did you copy it? I am afraid that you did not copy the necessary API function declaration, or it has been copied but you do not take it in consideration... Your function makes calls to `WideCharToMultiByte`, which must be on top of a standard module, if `Public`, or on top of the one keeping the code, if `Private`...